# PHP MongoDB remove document and return it

Tags: php, mongodb

Is there something like findAndModify() but for remove() in mongodb. I need to remove a document and in the same time to retrieve its contents.
I`m searching for a solution that does it in one "query" to the mongodb server.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain why you can not simply use two commands? Is there some other considerations that you have not mentioned?

Comment: I`m making a logging feature and i need the previous and new state of the document. In this case i already have an identifier of the document i want to remove. I`m looking for a concrete solution like this because i`m trying to optimize as much as possible because this will be done on all of the remove "queries" in the application

Comment: Since reads are concurrent as much as they like reading won't be a burden to you, deleting will, the biggest problem you might have is atomicity whereby you have to read separate to the delete in which case you might not get the true state, in which case you can use a deleted flag for all write operations and then remove the document later via cronjob or something

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution, but i risk data integrety, i`ll have to modify my application not to use documents which have delete flag. It seems that i`ll have to use select (synchronous (puke)) :D
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that mongo has this functionality. I also don't really see why you would need this. If you identify your documents correctly (and use indexes where possible), the remove action will be very quick and very efficient.

However, once you have retrieved the document you want to remove, you can use it's `_id` attribute to find it again for removal.

```
var doc = db.data.find( { "please": "delete me" } );
db.data.remove( { "_id": doc._id } );
```

Mongo indexes your collections by `_id` as a default, so when you use it to identify a document (as we are doing with remove), the actual operation is very efficient.

Comment: `findAndModify` does support `remove`, which I mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20887175/162228). It does serve a purpose, as you can't be completely sure that the document (or even the criteria) will not change between the `find()` and `remove()` operations in your example.

Comment: doesn't `.find()` return an array of objects? Wouldn't that make `doc._id` = `doc[0]._id` or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB's [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) command supports a `remove` option. It is mutually exclusive with the `update` option, so you would specify `remove` instead of providing `update` with a "new object" (atomic modifiers or a replacement document). Also, while the `new` option would normally allow you to return the document in its pre- or post-update state, it doesn't apply to `remove`.